# Latest best practices for Dropwizard metrics in GKE Stackdriver

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, dropwizard, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a Dropwizard application serving APIs from a GKE container. What are the best practices for getting the admin metrics (i.e. /metrics on the admin port) available in Stackdriver?  I expect they should show up in the google cloud platform's Monitoring -> Metrics Explorer interface.

Comment: Can you provide more details - what have you already tried and where you looked ? Have you looked at the custom metrics documentation ?
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/

Comment: The DW app I use has the admin interface enabled, which is generating a lot of metrics by default (which I can see via the /metrics endpoint on the admin interface.

From there it seems a reasonable path to getting JMX access to the same metrics via - https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.1.2/getting-started.html#reporting-via-jmx .  From there I don't know how to make the JMX information available to be ingested by Stackdriver.

I see some references to setting up Prometheus, but I was hoping I could get the metrics into Stackdriver instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to get you metrics into Stackdriver;

1. [JMX](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:GenericJMX) - some have managed to do that; I've managed to dig up this [tutorial how to monitor JVM's with JMX and Stackdriver](https://medium.com/google-cloud/monitoring-jvm-within-a-docker-container-using-stackdriver-e53f53e4f5d6) but can't verify it's a valid solution.
2. OpenCensus - for me it seems like more viable solution mainly due larger knowledgebase and (IMHO) better community support. Mainly because there's a documentation about [Dropwizard integration with StackDriver](https://opencensus.io/integrations/dropwizard/#background) and [creating exporters](https://opencensus.io/exporters/supported-exporters/java/stackdriver-stats/) (you have to use [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics)). And here's another tutorial [how to export Dropwizard metrics into Stackdriver](https://medium.com/@mayurkale22/export-dropwizard-metrics-to-opencensus-1e98851693f8).

Comment: Thanks @W_B.  I'll look into OpenCensus.